# How to read barcodes from a list of images in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, barcode

I'm working on a Flutter project where I need to read about 30 barcodes from a single image at once. However, I have not been able to find a suitable package that can do this for me. As a workaround, I have attempted to split the image into 30 smaller and equal parts and read the barcodes from each part individually
This is my code for splitting the image:

```
 List<Image> splitImageParts = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      List<int> imageBytes = await getImageBytes('assets/images/bs_image.png');
      imglib.Image? inputImage = imglib.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes));
      splitImageParts = splitImage(inputImage: inputImage!, horizontalPieceCount: 4, verticalPieceCount: 10);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<int>> getImageBytes(String imagePath) async {
    ByteData imageData = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
    Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
    return bytes.toList();
  }

  List<Image> splitImage({required imglib.Image inputImage, required int horizontalPieceCount, required int verticalPieceCount}) {
    imglib.Image image = inputImage;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    int width = (image.width / horizontalPieceCount).round();
    int height = (image.height / verticalPieceCount).round();

    // split image to parts
    List<imglib.Image> parts = <imglib.Image>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < verticalPieceCount; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < horizontalPieceCount; j++) {
        parts.add(imglib.copyCrop(image, x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height));
        x += width;
      }
      x = 0;
      y += height;
    }

    // convert image from image package to Image Widget to display
    List<Image> outputImageList = <Image>[];
    for (var img in parts) {
      outputImageList.add(Image.memory(imglib.encodeJpg(img)));
    }
    return outputImageList;
  }
```

Now I have a list of images, where each image is represented as an instance of the Image class and stored in a list (List<Image> splitImageParts). However, I have not been able to find a suitable package that can handle reading barcodes from images that are not captured by the camera or picked from the gallery.

I have tried adapting existing barcode scanning packages to work with a list of images, but have not been successful so far. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could accomplish this task, either by adapting an existing package or by writing custom code to scan the barcodes?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [flutter_zxing](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zxing)?  You can use the `readBarcode()` method to read the images

```
import 'package:flutter_zxing/flutter_zxing.dart';

List<String> barcodeResults = [];

for (var image in splitImageParts) {
  ByteData imageData = await rootBundle.load(imagePath);
  Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();

  //Decode
  Code? barcode = await FlutterZxing.readBarcode(bytes);

  if (barcode != null) {
    barcodeResults.add(barcode.rawContent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Texv. I have some questions.
First, what should I pass as the imagePath parameter? They are local variables in the code, not files. 
Second, I got an error, The getter 'rawContent' isn't defined for the type 'Code'.

Comment: oh sorry, about the second error use .content not .rawContent. As for the imagePath, it should work with local variables because we're using rootBundle, what error are you getting?

Comment: No problem. I think it isn't .content either. It should be .text, right? Because I do not see .content(I'm using the 1.1.2 version). And bout your question when I pass the image as its parameter,  I'm getting this error: The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.